# phpexcel - How to prevent importing when rows are empty

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am using Phpexcel framework. I want that if any row in excel sheet is empty then it should not import entire worksheet.

Is there any function/method?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Strictly speaking, PHPExcel is a `library`, not a `framework`

Comment: Thanks for this details. Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in PHPExcel method to do this, it's something you'd need to implement yourself after the workbook had been loaded when you are processing the spreadsheet rows

Comment: Any suggestion how can I show an error msg if mandatory columns are empty ?  Suppose there are 10 columns and If col1,2,5 are mandatory then How can I show an error?